# Как сделать заголовок с линией внизу

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, шаблоны

Как сделать подчеркивание слов, без использования `position:absolute`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подчеркивание должно быть жёлтой линией, как на рисунке.

Comment: чем position:absolute не нарвится?

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с `background: linear-gradient`

```css
body {
  background-color: #008aff;
  margin: 50px;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: monospace;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 2px rgba(999, 999, 999, 0.1);
  background: #ffd62c;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #ffd62c 40%, transparent 40%);
}
```

```html
<h1>Часто задаваемые вопросы</h1>
```

Вариант с использованием псевдоэлемента `:before` и свойства для него `position: absolute;`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #008aff;
  margin: 50px;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: monospace;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 2px rgba(999, 999, 999, 0.1);
}

h1:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 104%;
  height: 40%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -2%;
  background-color: #ffd62c;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Часто задаваемые вопросы</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Без переноса слов в заголовке:

```css
body { background-color: #008aff; }

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 35px auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font: 35px "Arial Black";
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #ffd52a 0.6em, transparent 0.6em);
}
```

```html
<h1>ЧАСТО ЗАДАВАЕМЫЕ ВОПРОСЫ</h1>
```

---

Вариант с переносом заголовка и использованием `box-shadow`:

```css
body { background-color: #008aff; }

h1 {
  display: inline;
  margin: 35px auto;
  font: 35px "Arial Black";
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -0.6em #ffd52a;
}
```

```html
<h1>ЧАСТО ЗАДАВАЕМЫЕ ВОПРОСЫ</h1>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol: когда я начал отвечать был только ваш ответ с абсолютом.